# How to correct the manipulation of elements in the child view in expandableListView android, when changing data in the item?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have this view with each item and, when I want to change the status due to an interaction, that item changes and also affects the others that are in the other view groups, but in different positions, in fact every 3 positions.

When updating the textView, other elements are updated as well, which should not be modified.

This image, show how is working the update on view.
Don't worry about the data, it's simulated for development.

https://i.postimg.cc/156kJRbM/ndice.jpg

```
@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                         View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_task, null);
    }

    final Task task = getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
    nameTask.setText(task.getTask());


    final  TextView nameTask = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTask);
    final  TextView tvDurationTask = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvDurationTask);
    final  TextView tvTimeRemining = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvTimeRemining);
    final View identifier = (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.identifier);
    final LinearLayout taskItem = convertView.findViewById(R.id.taskItem);
    final LinearLayout btnStartTask = convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnStartTask);

    tvDurationTask.setText(pomodorosTask[task.getPomodoros()]);

    taskItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mClickListener.onClickListener(task);
        }
    });

    btnStartTask.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            notifyDataSetChanged();
            //Here I want to update a view, but change another item too
            mClickListener.onStartPomodoro(task, view, tvTimeRemining);
        }
    });

    return convertView;

}
```

`

Comment: ¿Cuál es exactamente tu pregunta? What exactly is your question? Can you elaborate?

Comment: Lo que sucede es lo siguiente. Al actualizar el textView, se actualizan otros elementos también, que no deberían modificarsen. Obseve la imagen, puede dar más explicación.  
https://i.postimg.cc/156kJRbM/ndice.jpg
What happens is the following. When updating the textView, other elements are updated as well, which should not be modified. Observe the image, you can give more explanation.

Comment: ¿Donde es definido `task`? No veo una declaración.

Comment: @Christine Task es un POJO, ya lo coloqué en el código de la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: @Christine No sé porqué razón se modifica también otros items, si estoy pasando la vista que defino en cada uno y además cada widget está declarado como final. Si le doy en el botón Empezar, modifica el texto de ese item, pero otros items en un groupview diferente.